# Ember.js: Where is the "start" button?

Tags: ember.js

I'm used to thinking about a single-page application startup happening like this: 1. Bootstrap some data into critical models, 2. Instantiate a master controller, and 3. Call it's render() method to kick things off.

How is this accomplished with Ember? Following the (meager, sigh) examples in the documentation, it seems like things sort of kick off on their own when the page loads -- templates are compiled, views render like magic when the page loads. I feel like I am missing something fundamental. It there an example online of a more complex app, say something with tabbed or dynamically loaded views?

Lightbulb, going off it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you extend an ember Application object you can provide a ready function which will be called when the application starts. You have to make sure to call this._super() or else it will break your application. Check out my [sample sproucore 2.0 application](https://bitbucket.org/blktiger/contacts/src/e4655e95cf08/js/app.js) (ember is the new name of sproutcore 2.0).

The way that ember works is that it sets up a run loop which responds to events. Whenever an event fires, the run loop basically calls the necessary handlers and runs any bindings that need to be updated. Since everything typically happens in the run loop you often don't really write any code to update things. Instead you write bindings which are fired when needed.

Comment: Thanks.. This really helps clarify things for me. Sample app is great.. reviewing it in detail now!

Comment: Don't forget to checkout the contacts example application on the ember.js website as well.

Answer (score 4):

I've started a blog series about getting up and running with Ember on Rails. Here's Part 1:

http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/01/24/beginning-ember-js-on-rails-part-1/

I hope you'll find it useful, even if you're not planning to use Ember with Rails. Most of the interesting details are client-side and thus server-independent. The posts so far cover creating an Ember.Application object, loading data dynamically through a REST interface, and then rendering an Ember view on a page in handlebars. I hope it's enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks -- your posts were helpful. I like your super-simple REST library.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I've done is use an `Em.StateManager` to bootstrap.

```
App.Loader = Em.StateManager.create({
  start: Em.State.create({
    enter: function(mgmt, ctx) {
      // this code will execute right away, automatically
    }
  })
});
```

Since you use `create` instead of extend, the object will be instantiated immediately. If you define a state called `start`, it will be recognized as the default initial state (or you can specify another one by name). So the new StateManager object will immediately enter the initial state, and when the StateManager enters a new state, it will always look for a method of that state called `enter` and fire it if present.

A state manager is the natural place to initialize your app because the object provides ways for you to micromanage execution order during an async loading process without entangling yourself in too many callbacks.